# Computing the number of possibilities of functions.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

Suppose $A$ is a set of n distinct elements.What is the number of functions  $f:A\to A$  satisfying $f(f(x))=x$ for $x\in A$?

Comment: If you know the vocabulary about permutations and transpositions, you have all the transpositions, and combinations of transpositions as long as they have no common support.

Answer (score 2):

Such functions are *self-inverse permutations*, or *involutions*. If $f$ is an involution on $A$, for each $a\in A$ there are two possibilities: either $f(a)=a$, or there is a $b\in A\setminus\{a\}$ such that $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$. For each involution $f$ on $A$ let

$$F(f)=\{a\in A:f(a)=a\}\;,$$

the set of fixed points of $f$, and let $P(f)=A\setminus F(f)$. Then $P(f)$ must have an even number of elements, because $P(f)$ can be partitioned into pairs $\{a,b\}$ of distinct elements such that $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$. Thus, $P(f)$ can be split into $k$ pairs for some $k$ between $0$ and $\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ inclusive.

There are $\binom{n}{2k}$ ways to choose a subset of $A$ to be $P(f)$. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225743/why-are-there-frac2n2nn-ways-to-break-2n-people-into-partnerships) tells you that there are $\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$ ways to divide a set of $2k$ objects into pairs. Thus, for $k=0,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$ there are $\binom{n}{2k}\cdot\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}$ ways to choose a function $f$ for which $|P(f)|=2k$. Summing over the possible values of $k$, we see that there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}\frac{(2k)!}{2^kk!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{n!}{2^kk!(n-2k)!}$$

involutions on $A$.

If $a_n$ is the number of involutions on a set of cardinality $n$, the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is [OEIS A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085) in [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). The FORMULA section of the entry indicates that no nice closed form is known, though there is a nice recurrence:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}$$

for $n>1$, with initial values $a_0=a_1=1$. You should try to see why this recurrence holds; the reasoning is fairly straightforward.